# Traffic light colour change with no button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below and I need it to work automatically without the users input. Also It should be in a loop instead of going through the sequence once.
I tried to change the code but all it did was not work or change the shape of the traffic light.
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.lightbulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code should of been like this with the sequence and now button. But I can't make it the same shape as the first code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .traffic-light {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #000
}

.surround {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="surround">
      <div id="red-light" class="traffic-light"></div>
      <div id="yellow-light" class="traffic-light"></div>
      <div id="green-light" class="traffic-light"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function trafficLights() {
  var sequenceData = [
      [5, 1, 0, 0],
      [2, 1, 1, 0],
      [5, 0, 0, 1],
      [3, 0, 1, 0]
    ],
    lights = [],
    index = 0;

  for (var i = 0, elemId;
    (elemId = arguments[i]); i++)
    lights[i] = document.getElementById(elemId);

  function display() {
    if (index >= sequenceData.length)
      index = 0;

    for (var i = 0, cv, dLen = lights.length; i < dLen; i++)
      lights[i].style.backgroundColor = (sequenceData[index][i + 1] ? lights[i].id.match(/^[a-z]+/i).toString() : '#000');

    setTimeout(display, sequenceData[index++][0] * 977);
  }

  display();
}


window.onload = function() {
  trafficLights("red-light", "yellow-light", "green-light");
};
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a running jsfiddle would be much appreciated

Comment: What's 'jsfiddle'?

Comment: What's 'Google'?

Comment: @UweKeim What is "LMGTFY"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may try something like this :

```js
function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    if (counter == maxSec + 1) {
      return autoLights();
    }
    lightOne(counter);
    
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}

autoLights();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.lightbulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There should not be a button and the yellow should work after the red as well. I have added a new code to the question.

Comment: @anonymoususer you can check my new post, i have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

hi replace your script with following code.

```
//document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
        counter = 0; 
      //return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
autoLights(); // to auto call lighting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` .

```js
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;
autoLights();

var call = ['stopRed','slowYellow','goGreen'];
function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


var count = 0;

function timer() {
  setInterval(function() {
  count = count % 3;
  window[call[count]]();
   count++;
  }, 1000);
}

function autoLights() {
  timer();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.lightbulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>

<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="lightbulb"></div>
</div>
```